# Redirect from "/foo/bar/..." to just "/..." via .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I had all my website at `example.com/foo/bar/`. I now moved it to just `example.com/`, to improve readibility. How can I redirect via a .htaccess file all visitors that still go to `example.com/foo/bar` to `example.com/`?
I need all subdirectories to be redirectd too: for example from `/foo/bar/baz` to `/baz`, from `/foo/bar/baz/quax?id=5` to `/baz/quax?id=5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/bar(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) %1 [R=302,NC]
```

Comment: For more details use this: [.htaccess](https://gist.github.com/heiswayi/4f6a236a29c335475a2c)